# How do I type a variable that returns a function in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

This is my first stackoverflow question so please go easy on me, if there is any mistakes.

I wish to understand, how to typecheck a variable which returns a function in typescript, this functionn also returns a function, now how would I go about doing this

This is the variable I wish to type

```
function CarEngineClassifier({ Modal, CarName, CarType }:CarEngineClassifierProps) {........}
```

Now I already understand that CarName and CarType are simple strings, but the issue arises when typing out Modal, now Modal is a function...how do I know this?

I used a console statement to view what Modal is simply by doing console.log('This is a modal,Modal)

This was the output

```
ƒ Modal() {
  return setOpenModal({
    openModal: null,
    params: {}
  });
}
```

Now my question is how would I type "Modal" in my props

This is my props

```
  type CarEngineClassifierProps = {
  Modal: () => void;  //This isnt correct because the function is returning another function
  CarName: string;
  CarType: string;
}
```

Comment: _"a variable which returns a function"_... a **variable**? Did you mean a _function_ that returns a function?

Comment: Yes sorry my bad

Comment: From the duplicate, I find the second answer to be the better one

Comment: I have a question here, is Modal returning a function or returning the value returned from running a function?? I guess returning a function will mean
`function Modal(){ 
    return () => {/*Something here!*/};
}`

Comment: I still don't understand how I would go about implementing it